# How to set real time priority with psutil

Tags: python, process, psutil

How can I set real time priority with psutil. When I try this: `process.nice(psutil.REALTIME_PRIORITY_CLASS)` `REALTIME_PRIORITY_CLASS` results in `HIGH_PRIORITY_CLASS`.

Comment: Which OS, `psutil` Version. May I see `print(psutil.REALTIME_PRIORITY_CLASS)`.

Comment: Windows. Maybe I need to run it as admin. `>>> import psutil
>>> print(psutil.REALTIME_PRIORITY_CLASS)
256`

Comment: Please edit your Question to clarify: _**it sets priority to high but not real time**_. Does **high** working and only **realtime** NOT? Or does it mean `REALTIME_PRIORITY_CLASS` results in `HIGH_PRIORITY_CLASS`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem, running python with "as Administrator" solved the issue (On Win10 with python3.7).

Create a windows shortcut to "python " and set "Run as administrator" in the Advanced settings of the shortcut.

Comment: In addition to setting "Run as administrator" for the python, if you are running the python within a command-line interpreter (e.g., cmd.exe, or Cmder.exe in Windows), you need to set "Run as administrator" for the command-line interpreter itself.